# Blocking port subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, port

So lets say I have the following scenario.

`http://website.com:8080` and `http://website.com:8080/demo`

Is there any way for me to make the demo available to everyone but to keep the rest of port 8080 available only from specific ips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you create a virtualhost demo.website.com much more easy?